# Error: call revert exception Thirdweb NFT Drop

Tags: next.js, thirdweb

I am using Next.js, Thirdweb, VS Code, Sanity Studio

Snippet of my code:

```
const [claimedSupply, setClaimedSupply] = useState<number>(0)
const [totalSupply, setTotalSupply] = useState<BigNumber>()

const nftDrop = useNFTDrop(collection.address) < collection.address is correct
    
    
useEffect(() => {
   if(!nftDrop) return
    
   const fetchNFTDropData = async () => {
      const claimed = await nftDrop.getAllClaimed()
      const total = await nftDrop.totalSupply()
    
      setClaimedSupply(claimed.length)
      setTotalSupply(total)
   }
    
   fetchNFTDropData()
}, [nftDrop])
```

Full error: Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="nextTokenIdToClaim()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually means that you're connected to the wrong network. Double check the RPC url / desiredChainId / connected wallet is pointing to the right network.

Comment: It was with my desiredChainId. It was set on Mainnet but i used a testnet. Thanks!